# Sharepoint 2013 navigation breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, html, css, .net, sharepoint

I need help in adding navigation breadcrumbs to a SharePoint master page.

I have opened my master page in SharePoint Designer and turned on breadcrumbs but this not achieve what I want.

I want the default `hello>This is >Me` type of breadcrumbs.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ref :: http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/

By default SharePoint 2013 doesn’t have a breadcrumb (like the 2010 version used to have). This was a very helpful feature to navigate back in your site and some users really miss it.

The good news is Microsoft didn’t remove it from SharePoint 2013, it’s just hidden in the Seattle master page.

To get it back working, you can follow these steps:

1. Open your site with SharePoint designer
2. Navigate to All Files -> _catalogs -> master page
3. Edit the Seattle.master in advanced mode and copy all the code
4. By default it’s not possible to edit the original master. To create a new one click on File -> Blank Mater Page
5. Check out the new master, edit it in advanced mode, delete all the existent code and paste the one from the original Seattle
6. Search for `<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" style="display:none;">`
7. Delete the CSS attribute

   style="display:none;"
8. Two lines bellow change the visible attribute of the `SharePoint:PopoutMenu` to `true`
9. If you are using one of the themes from SharePoint your breadcrumb icon will not appear as it should, to get it back add the script below before the closing tag
10. Save the modified master page, check it in and publish the major version
11. Open your SharePoint Site, go to Settings -> Site Settings -> MasterPage under Look and Feel and select the new master page for the Site master and System master options
12. You will see a new icon on the left side of the menu.

Here’s your breadcrumb!